# Which figure is the odd one out(Puzzle)?

Tags: odd-one-out

Can someone points out which is the odd one? My guess was E, basis on the number to shapes in each square, only E contains odd number of figure while other contains even.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Puzzling Stack Exchange! Judging by the `12)` in front of the question, this puzzle probably has a source other than yourself. Do you mind sharing it with us?

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold until proper attribution of its original source is provided. It looks like you're asking us to solve a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content that you did not create yourself, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)** - at minimum you need to let us know where this came from, and any additional context you can provide is usually a big help to solvers. Posts which use someone else's content without disclosing where it came from are generally deleted.

Comment: you can search the image its available on internet. i copied this from a pdf file.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on interpretation, any of them is the odd one out:

A:

> Only one with a shape with more than 4 sides.

B:

> Only one with only one type of shape.

C:

> Only one in which some shapes do not touch each other.

D:

> Only one in which the total number of sides on all shapes is odd, assuming a circle is 1.

E:

> Only one with an odd number of shapes (as stated in the question)
>  or: only one in which one shape completely overlaps with another.

Comment: Since we assume there is only 1 answer, that invalidates all 5 interpretations of this puzzle.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D that also assumes it's a well-written question. I think Apep's point here is that it's not.

Comment: It could be that the goal of the question is not to see if the individual can find *the* correct answer, but *which* answer they find first and what that says about the way they approached the question.

Comment: @Apep, if that is correct this question is too broad for puzzling.se

Comment: athin's answer is imo clearly the intended one, and all of these seem like reaches, albeit creative ones.  Part of the puzzle for these kinds of puzzles is making a judgement about intention.  You can say there's no objectively "correct" answer, and in a way that's true, but in another way it's just refusing to play a game because the rules aren't completely unambiguous.

Comment: @Jonah Asserting that that solution is the only intended one implies that the creator included the overlapping of shapes on a whim. As you said, there is some judgment about intention. I believe that an obviously intentional aspect of the puzzle is not irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe, the answer is

> D

Because

> Count the sides. Only D has 5 sides, the others have 8.

Comment: Vs pvepyrf pbhag nf mreb fvqrf vafgrnq bs bar gubhtu, gur nafjre vf R sbe orvat gur bayl bar jvgu na bqq ahzore bs fvqrf [rot13](http://www.rot13.com/). That's why I'm not too keen on tests like this one; they don't test if you think well, they test if you think like the test-maker

Comment: This is obviously the intended answer.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:

> E, because the circle is in front of two other shapes (the triangle and the square) whereas in all the others, each shape overlaps only one other at most.

Answer (score -1):

> A

> Because the Pentagon is the only shape that doesn't appear twice.